# Migrate anaconda from python v3.6 to v3.7 and preserve all conda and pip packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

The latest anaconda distribution released on Sep2018 uses python v3.7. My existing anaconda distribution uses python v3.6

I would like to upgrade to this latest distribution which uses python v3.7. When I tried to install from the Windows installation executable file, there is no smooth upgrade. If I were to do a clean reinstall, I will have re-install all the conda and pip packages outside of the standard anaconda distribution that I am currently using.

How can I do an anaconda upgrade while preserving all these conda and pip packages that I am currently using that are out of the standard anaconda distribution?

I tried the following command;

```
conda list --explicit > environment_backup.txt
```

`environment_backup.txt` does not seem to contain the pip packages that I have installed.

I am fine if all the conda and pip packages cannot be preserved during the upgrade. However, I would like to have a convenient way to reinstall these conda and pip packages after the new version has been installed. It will be inconvenient if I have to run `conda install XXX` or `pip install XXX` commands individually.

Comment: You can't, not without at least re-installing all packages that require compilation into machine code. The Pure Python packages also benefit from having the `.py` files compiled to `.pyc` files, which are tied to the major.minor version too.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, So, there is no way to avoid doing `conda install XXX` and `pip install XXX` individually?

Comment: I didn't say *that* :-) You will have to re-install, but I'm sure `conda` can be made to list your installed packages and environments, and per environment, `pip freeze` can be made to list the currently installed packages so you can re-install them after upgrading.

Answer (score 3):

For the pip installed packages, you can similarly freeze your packages in a requirements.txt file and apply them in the new python version:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Or to only freeze local packages

```
pip freeze -l > requirements.txt
```

To restore the pip packages:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

`conda env exoprt` and `import` are your friends!
From [the conda docs](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment):

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

And then:

```
conda create --name myenv --file environment.yml
```

This does reinstall all packages but you know exactly which ones you had, including pip packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can update python with conda using:

```
conda update python
```

Make sure your conda also up to date by running

```
conda update conda
```

Alternatively you can create new enviroment and use the latest python by using.

```
conda create --name python37 python=3.7
```

And activate it with `source activate python37` in macOS or `activate python37` in windows (make sure to use Anaconda Prompt).

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not migrate `pip` installed packages, as far as I know, because the `site-packages` directory changes and conda doesn't migrate `pip`-installed packages...

Comment: I have verified that the pip-installed packages will not be migrated.

Comment: This will not migrate packages.